# Lower bound for mutual inner products of N random unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, N > n

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

I have $N$ independent random unit vectors $\{v_i\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where N > n. I need a concentration inequality of the form 
$$\text{P}(|v_i \cdot v_j| > \epsilon \,\,\,\, \forall i, j = 1, \dots, N: i \neq j)\leq \psi(\epsilon)$$
where hopefully $\psi(\epsilon)$ is something small.

I think that I can use Johnson-Lindenstrauss to do this for isotropic vectors (e.g. by choosing orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^N$ and projecting into $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a random subgaussian matrix).

Are there results of this form that hold when the $\{v_i\}$ are not distributed isotropically, for instance Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$? For instance, when there is some weak correlation/dependence between the components of each of the $v$ --- maybe $|\Sigma_{ij}| \leq \alpha$ when $i\neq j$?

(Any seemingly related results in this area are much appreciated!)

Comment: what is a quantifier for $i,j$?

Comment: Thanks. They run from $1\dots n$ and for the concentration they're not equal. I edited the question.

Comment: The first sentence in your post is inconsistent with the rest. What happened to the "independent" ?

Comment: Would this help $P(\cap_{i\ne j}\{|v_i^Tv_j| > \epsilon\}) \le \min_{(i,j) \mid i \ne j} P(|v_i^Tv_j| \le \epsilon)$ to begin with ?

Comment: @dohmatob You are right, I will remove the word 'independent'. 

Thank you for your second comment. I am not sure this is what I was looking for, but I will see whether I can make something from this observation.

Answer (score 3):

I have a partial answer: Lemma 2.2 (rephrased below) from [1] gives a deterministic lower bound to the inner product by considering the gram matrix

> Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ be a rank $d$, real, symmetric
>   matrix with $M_{ii} = 1$ $\forall i$ and $|M_{ij}| \le \epsilon$
>   $i\neq j$, then $$ \epsilon^2 \ge \frac{p - d}{d(p-1)}. $$

[1] Perturbed identity matrices have high rank: Proof and applications, 2009, Noga Alon

Comment: Interesting result to know. How do you intend to use it, given that for a full rank gram matrix (which is the precondition in the question) this would yield a trivial lower bound ($p-d = 0$)?

Comment: Very sorry. I made a typo in the question. I have $N$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and want to concentrate on all of them, not just $n$ of them. If $N>n$ then this lemma means I can't make the inner products arbitrarily small (which is also obvious, thinking geometrically).

$$|v_i \cdot v_j| \ge \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{n(N-1)}} \ge \sqrt{1/n}$$

Comment: In OP's setting, a simple union bound argument gives that $\max_{i\neq j}|v_i\cdot v_j|=O(\sqrt{(\log N)/n})$ with probability $1-O(1/N)$, so this bound (known as the Welch bound) is optimal up to logarithmic factors.

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon. Thank you. I looked at the wikipedia page for welch bounds. Can you explain how I would turn them into a probabilistic statement please? (If so then you could give an answer so I could accept.)